# Conditional group by and select query sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am having a query with conditional group by , i was just wondering is there a way to have select statement with that condition
my query is

```
select sum(totalamount),typetitle,
from #temp group by (case when  Type ='1' then typetitle else Type end)
```

with this query i get error at typetitle as its not in group by statement , is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tr like below

```
     select sum(totalamount),
    (case when  Type ='1' then typetitle else Type end)
    from #temp
     group by (case when  Type =1 then typetitle else Type end)
```

In group by projection column name and group by column have to be same

Comment: Only when `Type` and `Typetitle` have compatible data types.

Comment: @Ironsun is type and typetitle  both same data type?

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin no type is int and other is string but i can convert still same error

Comment: @Ironsun https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c0a51b417d6abe6a42caeda76166ed5d here is similar example though sample data is different could you please check this one

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin its working but i am not getting records for other condition i.e. type=2 etc , how can i include those records in this query?

Comment: @Ironsun share in fiddle where have not worked cause without sample its tough to say why not working

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to repeat the expression, then `apply` is one method:

```
select v.typegroup, sum(v.totalamount),
from #temp t cross apply
     (values (case when  Type ='1' then typetitle else Type end)
     ) v(typegroup)
group by v.typegroup;
```